# Clipped Circle Label In Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a triangle which has a [clip] path that is used to create a circle that looks like a arc to show the angle. I need to label it with a node as $\theta$. How can I achieve this? The current code places it at 0,0.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,3);
    \coordinate (C) at (4,0);
    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,left] {$o$} -- (C) node[midway,above] {$h$} -- cycle node[midway,below] {$a$};
    \path[clip] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \node[circle,draw=black,minimum size=40pt] at (C) (circ) {} node[above] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: img]

Comment: Append the node specification with `theta` to the path realized with `\draw`.

Comment: \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,left] {$o$} -- (C) node[midway,above] {$h$} -- cycle node[midway,below] {$a$} node[above] {$\theta$};
\path[clip] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\node[circle,draw=black,minimum size=40pt] at (C) (circ) {};

with that code it is stil above 0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are much better ways for denoting angles, e.g., the library `angles`. Also, the circle can be drawn by using the `\draw` command instead of realizing it as an empty node.

### Result

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (C) at (4,0);
%
\draw[thick,line join=round]
    (A) -- (B)
        node[midway,left] {$o$}
    -- (C)
        node[midway,above] {$h$}
    -- cycle
        node[midway,below] {$a$}
        node[pos=.18,above] {$\theta$};
\path[clip]
    (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) circle (30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```